# NextJS & json-server loading slow on localhost using getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building tiny e-commerce site and have setup my index page to generate static props as well as my individual product page cause we don't have many products yet. Issue I am experiencing is very slow loading on every single user click as if I missed something crucial in how data fetching works in NextJS.
So here are snippets below and full project can be found on: https://github.com/danieltosaba/framer-motion

**INDEX PAGE**

```
export default function Home({ blankets }: HomeProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0 }} initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{opacity: 1}}>
      <div>
        <Head>
          <title>Framer Motion Transitions</title>
        </Head>
        <main>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <h1>CHOOSE YOUR BLANKET</h1>
              </Grid>
              {blankets.map((blanket) => (
                <Grid key={blanket.id} item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
                  <Card>
                    <Link href="/product/[id]" as={`/product/${blanket.id}`}>
                      <a>
                        <img
                          src={blanket.imageUrl.cover}
                          alt={blanket.name}
                          className={classes.image}
                        />
                      </a>
                    </Link>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
        </main>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:4001/blankets/"
  );
  const blankets = await response.json();
  return {
    props: { blankets },
  };
};
```

**PRODUCT PAGE**

```
type ProductDetailsProps = Blanket;

export default function ProductDetails({ name, description, imageUrl, size, price }: ProductDetailsProps) {

  let images = [];
  imageUrl.url.forEach((img) => {
    images.push({
      original: img,
      thumbnail: img,
    });
  });

  return (
    <motion.div
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
    >
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <ImageGallery items={images} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper elevation={0}>
              <Card>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                    {name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                    Price: {price.small}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                    {description}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4001/blankets/${id}`
  );
  const blanket = await response.json();

  return {
    props: blanket,
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:4001/blankets/"
  );
  const blankets: Blanket[] = await response.json();
  const paths = blankets.map((blanket) => {
    return { params: { id: blanket.id.toString() } };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

Any help is more than welcomed!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After thoroughly reading documentation I found that

> In development (next dev), getStaticPaths will be called on every
> request.

Comment: Have you checked if it's better in production?. I change getStaticProps+getStaticPath (that was slow for me too) to getServerSideProps that is also called on every request, and this last one is much faster

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and also found this from [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development). In production it's fast because it's called at build time, but in development, it's very slow. Did you find a way to speed this in development apart from using `getServerSideProps`? I do not want to use `getServerSideProps` for what should be a static website

Comment: Hey Just check the commerec example and add local provider with 1000 products in SSG, and it take 17 min build!!! its very very SLOW :(

Comment: So, this is it? There isnt a way to speedup on development or run only one time? This is really annoying cause in production it is beautiful but in development its awful, even if u use next/link

Answer (score 4):

getStaticPaths will be called every single time you request a page in development. So if you have 500 products and if you are fetching all of them in getStaticPaths, means that on every page load you will loop through all of the items and you will create paths for each one of them. Just then getStaticProps will be called and your page rendered.

In production it will be different, because it will only build at "build time" and then rigenerate the pages on request from users, depending on the interval you set for the "revalidate" option.

But the best suggestion I can give is just to limit the number of data you request in getStaticPaths while developing. Hopefully we will get a better experience soon in development

Please correct me if I said anything wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions solves this problem by not pre-rendering any pages during development process.

Set environment variable `SKIP_BUILD_STATIC_GENERATION` to `true` for dev environments

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // When this is true (in preview environments) don't
  // prerender any static pages
  // (faster builds, but slower initial page load)
  if (process.env.SKIP_BUILD_STATIC_GENERATION) {
    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: "blocking",
    };
  }

  const posts = getAllPosts();// Could be you API request

  return {
    paths: posts.map((post) => {
      return {
        params: {
          slug: post.slug,
        },
      };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```